# Weird signed/unsigned integer division in C++

Tags: c++

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i = -100;
    unsigned u = 10;

    cout << "i = " << i << endl;

    i *= u;
    cout << "i*10 = " << i << endl;

    i /= u;
    cout << "i = " << i << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I wouldn't be asking the question here, if the output hadn't been:

```
i = -100
i*10 = -1000
i = 429496629
```

- In the case of multiplication, unsigned is implicitly converted to signed. So far, so good.
- However, In the case of division, signed is implicitly converted to unsigned, unsigned division performed; then converted back to signed.

Does anyone have any idea *why* this is happening? Because it does not make any sense to me.

P.S. The expected behavior is achieved by explicit typecast: `i /= (int) u;`

Comment: C & C++ are 2 different languages; which are you actually asking about?

Comment: Please don't tag other languages.

Comment: I'm asking about both since both C and C++ have the same behavior. The example code is given in C++, but the same result can be achieved in C too (just replace cout with printf)

Comment: Don't ask two different questions in the same post, then. The answers are governed by completely different specs.

Comment: *In the case of multiplication, unsigned is implicitely converted to signed. So far, so good.*  No, in the case of multiplication int is implicitly converted to unsigned.  That result is then converted to int, as part of the assignment.

Comment: I am not even sure the rules for integer promotion are exactly the same. But your signed integer gets implicitly converted to an unsigned integer before being divided. Long story short, don't let compilers implicitly convert your types for you (and don't mix signed and unsigned types)

Comment: The multiplication and division operations happen as if both are unsigned, then the assignment converts the unsigned back into signed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> In the case of multiplication, unsigned is implicitely converted to signed.

That is false.  When an `int` and `unsigned int` are used as operands to either the `*` operator or the `/` operator , the `int` argument is converted to `unsigned int`.

This is spelled out in section 8p11 of the [C++17 standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) :

> Many binary operators that expect operands of arithmetic or
> enumeration type cause conversions and yield result types in a similar
> way. The purpose is to yield a common type, which is also the type of
> the result. This pattern is called the *usual arithmetic conversions*,
> which are defined as follows:
>
> - (11.1) If either operand is of scoped enumeration type (10.2), no conversions are performed; if the other operand does not have the same
>   type, the expression is ill-formed.
> - (11.2) If either operand is of type long double, the other shall be converted to long double.
> - (11.3) Otherwise, if either operand is double, the other shall be converted to double.
> - (11.4) Otherwise, if either operand is float, the other shall be converted to float.
> - (11.5) Otherwise, the integral promotions (7.6) shall be performed on both operands. Then the following rules shall be applied to the
>   promoted operands:
>
>   - (11.5.1) If both operands have the same type, no further conversion is needed.
>   - (11.5.2) Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned integer types, the operand with the type of lesser
>     integer conversion rank shall be converted to the type of the operand
>     with greater rank.
>   - (11.5.3) **Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater than or equal to the rank of the type of the other
>     operand, the operand with signed integer type shall be converted to
>     the type of the operand with unsigned integer type.**
>   - (11.5.4) Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent all of the values of the type of the operand with
>     unsigned integer type, the operand with unsigned integer type shall be
>     converted to the type of the operand with signed integer type.
>   - (11.5.5) Otherwise, both operands shall be converted to the unsigned integer type corresponding to the type of the operand with
>     signed integer type.

The section in bold above is what applies here.

So in this expression:

```
i *= u;
```

Which is equivalent to this:

```
i = i * u;
```

The value of `i` which is -100 is converted to an `unsigned` value which (assuming a 32 bit `int`) is 4294967196.  The multiplication causes wraparound which results in 4294966296.  This value is then converted to `int` when assigned back to `i`.  This conversion is implementation defined although most implementations will simply reinterpret the representation as `int` which will result in the value -1000.

Then in this expression:

```
i /= u;
```

Which is the same as this:

```
i = i / u;
```

The same conversion happens as before, so the `int` value -1000 is converted to the `unsigned` value 4294966296.  The result of the division is then 429496629.  This value is in the range of an `int`, so it is unchanged when it is converted to `int` prior to being assigned to `i`.